# LDAPsearch overwrite ldap.conf parameter

Tags: ldap, openldap

In my `ldap.conf` I would need to set `TLS_REQCERT never` but would like to do it in my `ldapsearch` console command.
I reviewed the following page but I cannot find the correct parameter.
https://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman1/ldapsearch.1.html

How can I set this parameter using the console command `ldapsearch ...` to never?
Thank you for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set it as an [environment variable](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/9.0/html/administration_guide/ldap-tools-examples#ldap-envvar) beforehand :

```
LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never
```

> The SSL/TLS parameters can be set as either an environment variable or
>   within the OpenLDAP configuration, meaning set in
>   /etc/openldap/ldap.conf or the $HOME/[.]ldaprc profiles.